# Does Marmalade SDK support in app purchase?

Tags: mobile, in-app-purchase, marmalade

I am searching for the features supported by Marmalade SDK and could not find anything about in app purchase. Does anyone knows how to do it and can point me some resources about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marmalade supports in-app purchase for Android, iOS, blackberry and Windows phone 8. You just need to look at the particular platform specific API they have. For example check out their platform specific guide [here](http://docs.madewithmarmalade.com/native/platformguides.html).

Comment: Disclaimer: I've used only Android, iOS and BB10 in-app purchase and as far as my experience goes, it works excellent.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I think this a little strange, this information is not so easy to find. It makes a little more difficult the task of choosing a mobile framework.

Comment: Well, that's the universal problem with marmalade, you'll get used to with it in some time.